# Caliburn.Micro does not have "Bootstrapper" in a namespace in App.xaml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, caliburn.micro

EDIT: It seems that I finally made it to work. I asked an author of that post which I referred before and he said that it's a known issue. He also gave mi a workaround (in the comment below the post), so I consider this question as closed. But thanks to all of you for time spent with my problems :)

---

I'm trying to learn MVVM with Caliburn Micro framework, but I got problems from the beginning. I'm following [this](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-the-first-project/) tutorial and I got such a code in App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="Caliburn.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:caliburnMicro="clr-namespace:Caliburn">
<!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <caliburnMicro:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But I got an error:

> The name "Bootstrapper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Caliburn".

I got Caliburn Micro 1.5.2 from NuGet repository. Any ideas appreciated...

My Bootstrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace Caliburn
{
public class Bootstrapper : PhoneBootstrapper
{
    PhoneContainer container;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new PhoneContainer();

        container.RegisterPhoneServices(RootFrame);
        //container.PerRequest<MainPageViewModel>();

        AddCustomConventions();
    }

    static void AddCustomConventions()
    {
        //ellided  
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Presumably you've created the `Bootstrapper` class and it's located in the `Caliburn` namespace?

Comment: What do you mean by 'located in the `Caliburn` namespace? I got `namespace Caliburn { [...] }` in the class and it's in the root of Caliburn project in solution.

Comment: `xmlns:caliburnMicro="clr-namespace:Caliburn;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"` first off, if the Bootstrapper type is located (and is public and isn't abstract and has a public constructor) in the Caliburn.Micro.dll assembly.

Comment: When I changed that line I got another error: `Undefinied CLR namespace`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't particularly clear. I was just trying to make sure you'd defined your own `Bootstrapper` type like the one in the tutorial, and it was in the correct namespace (the error seems to suggest it can't be found). Will's advice about the keywords is worth checking.

Comment: provide your bootstraper

Comment: you don't forget change App.xaml.cs?

Comment: @jimpanzer no, I'm not. I change that like in the tutorial I read. Bootstrapper provided.

Comment: @kkoscielniak So whats the solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it is not clear what the solution is

Comment: In my case, I was using and referencing "Caliburn" package from Nuget (legacy), it got solved by switching to "Caliburn.Micro" (current development)

Answer (score 4):

You should define your own Bootstrapper type which derives from one of the Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper types. The resource in your application resources should then be an instance of this bootstrapper.

The easiest option whilst learning is to use the [Caliburn.Micro.Start NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Start/), and have a look at its bootstrapper implementation. The [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation) also describes the markup you should use in your App.xaml file.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try with Caliburn.Micro.Start package. Yeah, I found that documentation, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: I also use Caliburn.Micro.Start. That how I get error Error 1 The name "AppBootstrapper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1". Error 2 InitializeComponent(); Method must have a return type

Comment: Could you ask a new question with your code included

Comment: Caliburn is frustrating to get started.  publicEnemy's complaint arises from following the installation instructions precisely, but this appears to be incomplete.  The code calls for AppBootstrapper, but doesn't define that.

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone got confused, because you named your own namespace `caliburn`, so they thought you are trying to create an instance of the framework's bootstrapper so i suggest to alter your naming conventions. With that out of our way, instead of the bootstrapper directly into the application resources, try putting it in a resource dictionary like this:

```
<Application
x:Class="Caliburn.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:caliburnMicro="clr-namespace:Caliburn">
<!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it´s easy to solve. You need to override the method  OnStart in your Bootstrapper class and in this method set which is your root view.

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<ViewModels.ShellVM>();
}
```