# Caliburn.Micro and the Bootstrapper/BootstrapperBase Classes

Tags: caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

I thought I would check out Caliburn.Micro. Using the [old CodePlex documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper) I went to implement my inherited bootstrapper class (inheriting from `BootstrapperBase`) and there is no `BootstrapperBase/Bootstrapper` class in the [new `GitHub` version](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro).

I have since re-downloaded the [older CodePlex version](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) and I am back in business with the tutorials etc. and the `Bootstrapper` classes are available.

**What is happening in the latest version of Caliburn.Micro and why is there no `Bootstrapper` classes?**

---

Note, I have seen:

1. [Caliburn.Micro does not have "Bootstrapper" in a namespace in App.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548729/caliburn-micro-does-not-have-bootstrapper-in-a-namespace-in-app-xaml)

this does not help me.

Comment: In CM 2.0 they have split the library into one portable core component  *Caliburn.Micro* and specific libraries for the supported platforms. As far as I can tell, the *Bootstrapper* class is located in the platform specific libraries.

Comment: It's not. If you build the code for .NET4.5 the class does not get included...

Comment: there is bootstrapper it is platform specific now its BootStrapperBase it is located in the PCL you will have 2 Calburn.Micro assemblies now with v2.  Caliburn.Micro and Caliburn.Micro.Platform. Just built a fresh download of the source and opened the compiled 4.5 assemblies and it is indeed in there.. I am betting you are missing the Platform dll

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Rob Eisenberg's [blog post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2013/11/25/caliburn-micro-2-0-0-alpha2-is-here.aspx) on 2.0:

> - Remove Bootstrapper and PhoneBootstrapper, use BootstrapperBase and PhoneBootstrapperBase

There's a usage sample [here](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.Hello/Caliburn.Micro.Hello/HelloBootstrapper.cs).

Comment: I was following the tutorial here - http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/comment-page-1

I was stuck in the AppBootstrapper : BoorStrapper<AppViewModel> Which is no more. You led me to the solution. Thanks

Comment: The link to a usage sample is dead.